# The class 'User' does not have a default constructor. Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I am still pretty new to flutter/firebase and I am having issues getting some of my old code to migrate to the newest version of firebase.

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

import 'database.dart';

class AuthService {

  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  User _userFromFirebaseUser(User user) {
    return user != null ? User(uid: user.uid) : null;
  }

  // Auth change user stream
  Stream<User> get user {

    return _auth.authStateChanges().map(
            (User user) => _userFromFirebaseUser(user)
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The [`User` class from `package:firebase_auth`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/User-class.html) does not provide any public constructors.  Do you intend to construct some other `User` class?  If so, you either will need to rename the other if possible or import using a [library prefix](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#specifying-a-library-prefix).

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that you have conflict in user model in imports so i just named database import file as db and used the User in it with `db.User`

I think it will work like this

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

import 'database.dart' as db;

class AuthService {

  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  db.User _userFromFirebaseUser(User user) {
    return user != null ? db.User(uid: user.uid) : null;
  }

  // Auth change user stream
  Stream<db.User> get user {

    return _auth.authStateChanges().map(
            (User user) => _userFromFirebaseUser(user)
    );
  }
}
```